# How to access the plugin event in Joomla 4

Tags: plugin-events

plugin code

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;
use Joomla\CMS\Event\Event;
use Joomla\Event\SubscriberInterface;

class PlgMygroupMyplugin extends CMSPlugin //implements SubscriberInterface
{
    
protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

protected $app;

//public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
//{
//  return [
//      'getMyevent' => 'getMyevent',
//  ];
//}

/*
*
*/
public static function getMyevent()
{
    return 'OK!';
}
}
```

I try to call in different ways all unsuccessfully

```
protected function getOptions()
    {
    
    PluginHelper::importPlugin('mygroup');
    
    $results = Factory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('getMyevent');
    
    
    //$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
    //$results = $dispatcher->trigger( 'getMyevent' );
    
    
    //$dispatcher = Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->getDispatcher();
    //$event      = new Joomla\Event\Event('getMyevent');
    //$results    = $dispatcher->dispatch('getMyevent', $event);
    
    
    //$dispatcher = Factory::getApplication()->getDispatcher();
    //$event = AbstractEvent::create('getMyevent', array());
    //$results = $dispatcher->dispatch('getMyevent', $event);

print_r($results);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that most likely all events should start with **"on"** when a different prefix is specified, as in my case the **"get"** event simply does not fire. **I changed the prefix to "on" and it worked.**

```
use Joomla\CMS\Plugin\PluginHelper;
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

PluginHelper::importPlugin('mygroup');
$results = Factory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onMyevent');
```

The solution is found on this page
[issues.joomla.org](https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/20966)

Comment: `triggerEvent` is deprecated in J4. 
The proper way is to create an Event and dispatch it.
You can find an example here: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/a94decccac55949997c6fd0227b26abfc5457fec/administrator/components/com_content/src/Model/ArticleModel.php#L900